# How to bind Data to Dropdownlist in Kendo Ui Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ios, kendo-ui

I have been using Kendo Mobile to develop an application, previously same application i have  done in Kendo web,it's works fine.The main problem is that i have to bind data to two dropdownlist which the below code i have written,when my application is running it show an error like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'append'".

in HTML

```
<div id="forms" data-role="view" data-title="Form Elements" data-init="initForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label style="margin-left: 20px">
                    Company:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlCompany" style="width: 200px">
                    <option>Select Company</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="style1">
                <label style="margin-left: 20px">
                    Category:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlCategory" style="width: 200px">
                    <option>Select Category</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label style="margin-left: 20px">
                   Product :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlProduct" style="width: 200px">
                    <option>Select Product</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

   function initForm() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "FlashReportMobileWebService.asmx/GetCompany",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    ddlCompany.append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].Company).html(data.d[i].Company));
                };


                $("#ddlCompany").kendoDropDownList();
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "FlashReportMobileWebService.asmx/ToCategoryDropDown",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    ddlCategory.append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].Category).html(data.d[i].Category));

                };
                $("#ddlCategory").kendoDropDownList();
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    $("#ddlCategory").change(
        function (e) {
            var ddlProduct= $("#ddlProduct");  
            var dataItem = $("#ddlCategory").val();  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'Category':'" + dataItem + "'}",
                url: "FlashReportWebService.asmx/ToFillProductDropDown",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlProduct.empty();
                    for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        ddlProduct.append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].ProductName).html(data.d[i].ProductName));
                    };
                    $("#ddlProduct").kendoDropDownList();
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
```

thanks for reading this

Comment: Darin is right.  Your ddlCategory and ddlProduct are both undefined in the provided code snippet.  Is ddlXXX a jquery element?  Chances are it isn't that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: I'm defining the ddlComapny,ddlCategory,ddlProduct in the script tag where these are binding from web service "FlashReportMobileWebService" by using ajax.The way i'm showing perfectly working fine for the web(Kendo) but problem with this code in mobile(Kendo).

Comment: I'm sorry to check the code i have modified it can recheck it can you people tell where's the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FlashReportMobileWebService.asmx/GetCompany",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var dataSource = [];
            for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {                    
                ddlCompany.push({ "Company": data.d[i].Company})
            };
            $("#ddlCompany").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "Company",
                dataSource: dataSource
            });
        }
    });
```

Write the above mentioned code instead of appending values to the ddlCompany.Values will bind.

Comment: seeems like it should have been dataSource.push instead of ddlCompany.push?